# Scrolling Twitter Feed Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter

So I'm trying to create a scrolling twitter feed. I followed the instructions from this tutorial.

http://andreaslagerkvist.com/archives/2011/06/24/how-to-create-a-scrolling-twitter-feed-using-jquery/

It doesn't work properly.  Starts to load then goes white. I noticed something in the comments that suggested how to correct the problem, which I thought I implemented properly, but it still doesn't work.  If someone's familiar with this, what code needs to be changed from the original in order to get this to work?

I believe it has something to do with this:

```
// This replaces the <p>Loading...</p> with the tweets
            insertLatestTweets: function (username) {
                var limit   = 5;    // How many feeds do you want?
                var url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name= + username + '&count=' + limit + '&callback=?';

                // Now ajax in the feeds from twitter.com
                $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                    // We'll start by creating a normal marquee-element for the tweets
                    var html = '<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left">';

                    // Loop through all the tweets and create a link for each
                    for (var i in data) {
                        html += '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + username + '#status_' + data[i].id_str + '">' + data[i].text + ' <i>' + Twitter.daysAgo(data[i].created_at) + '</i></a>';
                    }

                    html += '</marquee>';
```

Comment: show your code, and any errors your console shows we cant help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the twitter snippet that might be useful for your scenario..

```
     <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/ESPNcricinfo/cricketers-on-twitter"
     data-widget-id="286832583709442048" style="width:320px; margin-bottom:20px; 
    height:290px;" width="320" height="290" data-theme="light"  
    data-link-color="#0084B4">Tweets from @ESPNcricinfo/cricket-tweeters</a>




    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)

    [0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){
js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfm3C/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has depreciated the version of their API that you are trying to use.

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.", "code": 68}]}
```